# Having a big picture view of analysis

Tags: real-analysis, intuition

I have been studying (real and complex) analysis lately, both independently and part of my college courses. While I don't have that much of a problem following thee theorems (I can prove say most of them by myself without seeing the book's proof) or with the exercises, I don't possess a big picture of what I'm learning.

When I am reading a theorem with multiple lemmas and the theorem is pretty long and/or tricky, I can locally understand the proof of the lemmas and how one lemma follows from the other but I get so much bogged down in the details that I completely lost track of the big picture/intuition regarding the theorem ! I also lose track of the obstacles of the proof and how they're overcome (rather my attention shifts on understanding the lemmas locally).

Among the theorems which are relatively short and whom I can at least have an intuition just about how the theorem is proved, I see  don't really understand how the proof fits into the natural context of the theory or how the proof techniques generalize to other problems (eg when I use this seemingly random trick used in this proof to solve some other classes of problems ?) ?

How can I approach analysis so that I get at least *some* sense of the big picture and stuff and don't get completely lost in the details?

Comment: hello myself from 3 years ago. "While I don't have that much of a problem following thee theorems (I can prove say most of them by myself without seeing the book's proof) or with the exercises, I don't possess a big picture of what I'm learning." This is really good. What you're worrying about is very normal, and you should keep doing what you're doing (as said in what I quoted), except for worrying about what you asked about. The best thing you can do is just to keep going (maybe go back once in a while and see how everything is starting to fit together), and as time goes on and you learn...

Comment: more, things will start making more sense. The most annoying and difficult thing for me (and probably most other people) by far is learning a brand new subject, because of the reasons you brought up. I guarantee that any second course in complex or real analysis will be much more natural the first time you go through it than the first time you're going through what you are going through now

Comment: Oh, one thing I didn't quite see. Although, like I said, it's okay to not see how everything fits into a big picture, you should put some effort into understanding the theorem statements when you see them. Also, it definitely would take *a lot* of time to understand how the proof of the theorem gets around certain obstacles, etc, but it might be a good time investment to try to motivate the proof to yourself. Actually, now thinking about it, you should definitely put the time in to get a global (as opposed to local) idea of the proof of a given theorem. it will take a lot of time, but it's...

Comment: worth it for beginning real and complex analysis courses.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks a lot for your comments! They're pretty hope/helpful :) So for a concrete example, How can I have intuition regarding, say, what kind of obstacles do pop up in Reimann integration such that it don't follow dominated convergence theorem but how intuively Lebesgue integration allows us to go over it ? (Again, I understand the proof of dominated convergence, but I don't have intuition regarding the particular obstacle that is surpassed by switching from Reimann to Lebesgue)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean mathematically. In any event, do you have particular examples in mind? The first step is always generating examples. Getting intuition takes a lot of work...

Comment: @Lelouch My intuition there is the fundamental problem of when you are aloud to switch two limit processes and that really is only allowed under pretty strong requirement. Saying this, I am also lying actually. Because this is not at all my intuition but really the result of my extensively studying this stuff for years now and get the point where this completely abstract mind boggling stuff becomes somewhat so familiar that I have developed something like a feeling or intuition, I guess. I have to back mathworker: Give yourself time:

Comment: Modern analysis is the result of one of the most fascinating collaborations of the human mind. To not _get it_ in 12 month sounds to me like the most naturally thing.